# Grub rescue for dual boot linux os

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

Two days ago I tried to install debian linux alongside ubuntu just because of some recommendations, but yesterday I deleted the whole debian os and it seems that ubuntu's boot loader wont work and I'm face grub rescue. Any answer I found on internet was for windows alongside linux and so now I can't recover my files on  ubuntu partition, any one can help?

Comment: You can probably get your files relatively easily - boot into a live usb session (‘try Ubuntu’), you’ll hopefully then be able to mount your previous Ubuntu partition to access / back to the files.

Comment: FYI: It won't be Ubuntu's boot loader that doesn't work, by installing Debian last, you replaced the prior Ubuntu boot loader with a Debian one, then by removing the Debian partition you broke the Debian controlled `grub`. The *break* was done by whomever deleted the Debian partition (ie. *last installed*) that controlled booting.   If you want to remove a partition in future; always ensure that OS/partition isn't used in the booting process before you delete/remove it  (by default it's the last OS installed unless you specifically changed ownership of boot via command)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: (you didn't install windows, but removing Debian when it controlled the booting of your box achieved the exact same thing...)

Answer (score 0):

Huh, finally loging in to ubuntu without reinstalling :)))
First I should say that I didn't want to put this question behind so I will share my answer

I found something here that can help anyone if my respond won't work on their computers: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

I made a bootable USB stick to reinstall Ubuntu, then I chose secure boot password again and in partitioning tab I chose something else... And then changed bootloader location to my /boot directory, then I restarted computer, opened up BIOS and chose /boot again for loading and after a while Ubuntu started normally without missing any files!